# ¿Cómo crear un método en Laravel 8.X accesible en todos los controladores?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Mi problema es fácil de comprender, básicamente necesito hacer un método que procese los parámetros para procesarlos y así devolver el resultado, hasta aquí todo bien mi pregunta es **¿Cómo hacer que este método sea accesible desde todas las clases de Controllers de la manera "correcta" en Laravel 8.X?**

Aparentemente la manera correcta es usarlo como Helper, he ingresado el archivo a app/Helpers/Pictures.php

El método de hecho es el siguiente:

```
<?php
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

function encodePicture($input)
{
    $resize = 400;
    return Image::make($input)->resize($resize, $resize, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
    })->encode('jpeg');
}
```

¿Cómo lo añado al autoload?

Comment: ¿Me puede dar un Link o información que pueda tomar como ejemplo que le haya funcionado a usted?

Comment: Listo, ya está actualizado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Esta respuesta es una aproximación y no pretende ser una solución absoluta**

1. En tu composer.json puedes registrar en la clave autoload una nueva llamada Helpers con una estructura similar a esta:

   ```
    "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/",
                ..............................,
                ..............................,
                "Helpers\\": "helpers/"
            }
   ```
2. Posterior en la raíz de tu proyecto creas una nueva carpeta llamada *helpers*
3. Dentro de dicha carpeta creas un archivo llamado Codifica.php con una estructura como esta:

   ```
    <?php

    namespace Helpers;

    use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

    class Codifica
    {

        function encodePicture($input)
        {
            $resize = 400;
            return Image::make($input)->resize($resize, $resize, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->encode('jpeg');
        }
    }
   ```
4. Ahora ejecuta el siguiente comando:

   ```
    composer dump-autoload -o
   ```
5. Finalmente para poder usar este método en tu controlador puedes hacer esto:

   ```
    use Helpers\Codifica;

    class EjemploController extends Controller
    {
        public function otro(Codifica $codifica)
        {
            return $codifica->encodePicture(aqui_el_valor_a_pasar);
        }
    }
   ```

O tal vez una *mejor aproximación* sería:

- No envolver al método en una clase (*puede lucir como algo no adecuado y sobrado*)
- Dejar el método dentro de un [*trait*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php)
- Al archivo donde almacenas el trait que podemos llamar: *Codificador.php* lo componemos de esta forma:

  ```
    <?php // helpers/Codificador.php

    namespace Helpers;

    use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

    trait Codificador {
        function encodePicture($input)
        {
            $resize = 400;
            return Image::make($input)->resize($resize, $resize, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->encode('jpeg');
        }
    }
  ```

Posterior, para usarlo en tu controlador, haces lo siguiente:

- Importa por su namespace:

  ```
    use Helpers\Codificador;
  ```
- Posterior lo *usas* dentro de tu clase controlador así:

  ```
    use Codificador;
  ```
- Ahora para hacer uso del método que posee dicho *trait* hacemos lo siguiente:

  ```
    public function loQueSea()
    {
        return $this->encodePicture(valor_a_codificar);
    }
  ```

**Nota importante**: Esta segunda propuesta sigue requiriendo que se cree la clave en el *autoload* y que se lleve a cabo el comando `composer dump-autoload -o` mencionados en los puntos 1 y 4.

**Edición**

> Aunque pueden considerarse en su forma actual propuestas funcionales, involucran una serie de pasos un tanto innecesarios:

- Laravel tiene incluido un [*Service Container*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#introduction)
- Dicho *Service Container* puede resolver automáticamente
- Entonces involucrar en el autoload un *namespace* para esto no luce como la mejor opción *salvo que se justifique su uso*

Entonces retomando ambas propuestas podemos hacer los siguientes cambios:

1. No registres el namespace en el composer.json
2. No ejecutes el comando [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) pues no se necesita actualizar el autoloader
3. Los demás pasos se pueden llevar a cabo
4. Si accedes a **`src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php`** toma nota en la sección donde se importan por medio de su namespace algunas clases, entre ella una que se llama [**`ReflectionClass`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.reflectionclass.php) la cual es usada para obtener información de la clase (*si usas un IDE te ayuda a conocer mas sobre esto gracias a los docblocks*).

De este último punto te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Ejemplo;

class Clase
{
    /**
     * retorna un objeto con la fecha, el tipo de zona horaria y la zona horaria 
     * 
     * @return a new DateTime object
    */
    
    public function metodoClase(): \DateTime
    {
        return new \DateTime();
    }
}


print_r(new \ReflectionClass(Clase::class));
```

Que te da una salida como esta:

```
ReflectionClass Object
(
    [name] => Ejemplo\Clase
)
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona ¡Muchas gracias!