# Como llamar a un metodo de otros archivos estando en un controlador

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un problema que no puedo encontrar en páginas y videos, no es muy complicado. Espero que me puedan ayudar, se los agradecería muchísimo.

El problema es: tengo que utilizar una función de un controlador que se encuentra en otro archivo (Uso laravel en un servidor)

Tengo este código que se encuentra en la carpeta app/http/carpeta1/carpeta2

```
if($resultados[0] == 'true'){
                            DB::table('orders')->where('orders_id', $order->orders_id)->update(['bbva_id' => $resultados[1], 'url' => $resultados[2] ,'bbva_status' => $resultados[3]]);  
                            $metodo = "BBVA Bancomer";
                            $pagado = trim($resultados[3]);

                            //LLamo a la función nameFunction(parametro1, parametro2){}
                            
}
```

El otro archivo con el método que tengo que llamar se encuentra en app/models/carpeta1/carpeta2

```
class Order extends Model{

     public function updateRecordByID($orders_id, $orders_status){
           //Operaciones
     }
}
```

¿Como puedo llamar a ese método sin usar un include?

Comment: Agrega por favor que has intentado, revisa si esto te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/409260/c%c3%b3mo-crear-un-m%c3%a9todo-en-laravel-8-x-accesible-en-todos-los-controladores/409274#409274

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta, espero que sea entendible

Comment: Haces un trait o una clase Helper y la llamas en tus controladores.

Comment: pero en tu controller ya estás actualizando directo la tabla orders, qué se supone que hace el método?